# Can clear push a notification when kill app for me?

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

I'm coding to store a notification when app was killed and i have a problem here! When receive a notification on Notification Center, I click on it and anything work well, but when I receive a notification on Notification Center, I click on app icon to run app and then look like my app do not receive anything! In my debug progress I can see "launchOptions" in:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    self.pushNotificationPayload = [launchOptions valueForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
}
```

is nil if I run app by way click on app icon! Someone can tell my why?

Comment: Are you talking about push notifications or local notifications? Do you start the app by tapping on the notification, or the app icon from the home screen (springboard)?

Comment: I am using Push notification and start app by click on app icon

Comment: Try to start the app by tapping on the notification banner (or from Notification Center)

Comment: yes! it work very well, but Is there a way to store this notifi to local database when run app by click on icon?

Answer (score 0):

Your app can get notification that the remote notification has been received through the [`application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623013-application?language=objc) method explained in [Handling Remote Notifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/HandlingRemoteNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH6-SW1).

When your app is in the background, it can save the data needed and you can retrieve that data the next time you launch the app.